# Is 'that's not the right tool, here's why' an acceptable answer to a question about a tool?

Tags: discussion

Long time stackoverflow user here; new user to webmasters though.

Can anyone clarify if answers that suggest that the user is using the wrong tool for the task they've outlined (with an explanation why) should be closed as 'not answering the question' in webmasters?

Such answers appear acceptable on stack overflow. Does webmasters prefer them to be comments rather than answers?

Comment: For me it would depend.  Did you have a specific case in mind?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Yes; https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/59813/reduce-likelihood-of-mailchimp-email-campaign-going-to-spam/108022?noredirect=1#comment138222_108022 (for those that can't see deleted answers; I'd essentially stated that in my experience mailchimp is a significant source of spam, so preventing mailchimp mails going into spam traps is essentially an intractable problem)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thanks for the suggestion for more facts & workable alternatives - I've updated the answer by editting. The 'undelete' button doesn't work though; is the expectation that I should flag, or add my new answer using 'Add another answers'?

Comment: I've undeleted it for you.   With your edits it addresses the question well enough now.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Great, many thanks for your help!